# Phoenix link confirmation popup appears multiple times

Tags: popup, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using `Elixir 1.7.2` + `Phoenix 1.3` and I've a delete link that has a data prompt of `"Are you sure?"` before confirming the deletion.

[image: are-you-sure]

The problem is, when you click the `delete` button in the application it asks for multiple consecutive `"Are you sure?"` confirmations (sometimes as many as 6) before it actually allows you to delete.

The code for the delete link is:

```
<%= link to: project_document_path(conn, :delete, project, document),
          method: :delete,
          data: [confirm: "Are you sure?"] do %>
  <img class="absolute k-w2-5 top-0 left-1" src="/images/delete.svg" />
<% end %>
```

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour in Phoenix with links that have confirmation prompts and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because we were requiring our javascript file in multiple locations, one for each time we were calling a javascript function. We now have one instance of our require in our `app.html.eex` file which covers our whole view file tree. This is the code that was replicated:

`<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>`